# SQL clean repeated results in one column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this query result, with two columns, BU and OPTION

```
BU    OPTION
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        1
B        2
B        3
```

Is there any way to obtain the result like this?

```
BU    OPTION
A        1
         2
         3
B        1
         2
         3
```

Comment: Not really an SQL issue. Usually done in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. I don't know why but I was thinking in something more dificult. It was too early in the morning ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be handled better on the presentation layer, you could still achieve it via

```
SELECT case when rw = 1 THEN Bu ELSE '' END AS BU, Option FROM (

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by bu order by bu, option) as rw, * FROM #AA
) X
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with CTE as
(
select MT.*, row_number() over(partition by MT.BU order by MT.Option) as rn
from MyTable
)
select case when rn = 1 then BU else null end as BU,
       CTE.Option
from CTE
```

But as Jarlh said, this is best handled at the presentation layer

Answer (score 1):

I assume that bu is visible when option = 1

```
select
(case when option = 1 then bu else '' end) as bu,
option
from your_table
```